# Dúvida Sobre a segurança do 'openssl_encrypt'

Tags: php, criptografia, openssl

Olá, Estou com algumas duvidas sobre este método de encriptar dados, pois pretendo utilizar entre a versão 5.6 ate a versão atual do PHP e possuo duvida se ira rodar sem problemas.
Estou com o seguinte Código abaixo, caso alguém possua alguma sugestão para melhora-lo, pois pretendo utilizar para codificar textos e decodifica-los e sera uma grande quantidade de palavras. Desde já  Grato!

```
function encode($data)
{
    $pass = 'my serial key';
    $IV1   = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC')));
    $IV2   = substr($IV1, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));
    $enc = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $pass, 0, $IV2);
    return trim(base64_encode($enc . '::' . $IV2), '=');
}

function decode($data)
{
    $pass = 'my serial key';
    $IV1   = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC')));
    list($data, $IV1) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);
    $IV2   = substr($IV1, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));
    $dec = openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $pass, 0, $IV2);
    return trim($dec);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Em resumo vou listar os "problemas" que tem no seu código:

- Sua entropia máxima diminuiu de 128 para 96 por causa do `base64`, sem vantagem alguma.
- Sua cifra escolhida (AES-CBC) não protege contra edições de texto.
- Sua "chave" parece ser uma senha, não uma chave.
- Suportar versões obsoletas não me parece ser uma vantagem.

---

Primeiro, acredito que é melhor eliminar o suporte para o PHP5.6 e PHP 7, por dois motivos:

- O PHP 5.6 e PHP 7.0 não são mais suportados pelo próprio PHP.
- O PHP 5.6 (até o PHP 5.6.12) possui uma vulnerabilidade no `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`, que usava o `RAND_pseudo_bytes` do OpenSSL, que é inseguro.

---

Segundo, você não diz o objetivo que deseja cumprir, nem os ataques que pretende mitigar, então sem uma lista de vetores de ataque é impossível "melhorá-lo". Mas, uma coisa que é possível notar é que o seu código NÃO protege contra edições de texto, você pode decifrar um texto alterado, sem qualquer sinal de que o texto foi alterado ou não. Isso é um problema para você? Não sabemos.

---

Terceiro, você está usando o `base64_encode` sem sentido algum e está diminuindo a entropia máxima do `IV`. Observe as seguintes linhas:

```
$IV1 = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC')));
$IV2 = substr($IV1, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));
```

O AES-256-CBC precisa de um vetor de inicialização (`IV`) de 16 bytes. O $IV1 terá 24 bytes, entretanto cada byte somente terá 6 bits úteis (afinal para cada 3 bytes são 4 bytes de Base64). Portanto, sua entropia máxima caiu de 128 bits para 96 bits, sem qualquer vantagem ou motivo claro para tal.

---

Quarto, você parece usar uma senha. Senha não são chaves (se quiser usar senhas como chaves terá que usar algum PBKDF, como o Argon2id). Se não for senhas, crie uma chave uniformemente aleatória. Não sei se isto foi apenas um exemplo, entretanto o nome de `$pass` me levantou tal suspeita.

---

Descartando o suporte para tais versões, poderia usar o `random_bytes` e poderia usar o LibSodium (que usa o Salsa20, ao invés do AES, e usa o Poly1305 para autenticação).

```
$chave = "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xFE\xED\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xFE\xED\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xFE\xED\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xFE\xED"
// Sua chave

function encode($data) {
    $nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES);
    return unpack("H*", $nonce)[1] . sodium_crypto_secretbox($data, $nonce, $chave);
}

function decode($data) {
    $nonce = pack("H*", substr($data, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES * 2));
    return sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($data, $nonce, $chave);
}
```

Se o suporte para o PHP 5.6 é realmente necessário, não muito a se fazer (exceto corrigir o Base64), Mas, o PHP 5.6 não suporta nativamente o AES-GCM, até onde eu saiba, teria que fazer alguma "gambiarra" usando AES-CBC + HMAC.